# generate url is not working in symfony2

Tags: symfony

Hi thanks for helping me in all the times. I created a login form when admin logins it displays all the userslist with add,delete,edit options

and my view code for successfull login and displaying users list is something like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('deleteuser',array('id'=>$id,))?>">Delete</a>
<td><a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('edituser',array('id'=>$id))?>">Edit</a></td>
```

When admin clicks in delete option of a particular it will generate id of particular user in the url somthing like this `url:deleteuser?id=6`

For this routing i have a controller deleteuser with delete action which again create a view for the confirmation whether to delete the user or not.Even when i click the no button my user is deleting 
my controller for deleteuser is

```
class deleteuserController extends Controller
{
public function showAction(Request $request)
{
$request = $this->getRequest();

     $register = new users();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

   $repository = $em->getRepository('RepairStoreBundle:users');

    $result = $repository->display();
  return $this->render('RepairLoginBundle:login:success.html.php',array('result'=>$result,)); 

}   
public function deleteAction(Request $request)
{

 $id= $_GET['id'];  
  $request = $this->getRequest();

     $register = new users();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $repository = $em->getRepository('RepairStoreBundle:users');

if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{ 

 $register = $repository->find($id);

  $result = $repository->display();
  return $this->render('RepairLoginBundle:login:success.html.php',array('result'=>$result,));
}
 return $this->render('RepairLoginBundle:admin:deleteuser.html.php');
 }



}
```

My `routing.yml` file is

```
delete:

pattern:   /delete

defaults:  { _controller:RepairLoginBundle:deleteuser:show}

deleteuser:

pattern:   /deleteuser

defaults:  { _controller:RepairLoginBundle:deleteuser:delete}
```

This is my `delete.html.php`

```
<div class="modal-footer">  
<a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('deleteuser')?>">

<input type="submit" name="Yes" class="btn btn-success" value=Yes /></a>

<a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('delete')?>"><input type="submit" name="No" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" value="No"/></a>
</form>
</div>
```

Even after clicking no it is not generating delete route it can you please tell me where I made mistake

Comment: I read about 4 times your question and I am still not sure what your issue is but why are you putting your `input` inside some `a` links??

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using Twitter Bootstrap and it's not clear where your code is failing, but your HTML is wrong.

Try this instead:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#" class="btn">Cancel</a>
  <a href="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('deleteuser', array('id' => $id); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Delete user</a>
</div>
```

See documentation: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

As a side note, your controller and route definition could benefit from reading the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/routing.html), it may work (does it?) but it's definitely not within best practice!

Your routing should look like this:

```
deleteuser:
  path:      /deleteuser/{id}
  defaults:  { _controller:RepairLoginBundle:deleteuser:delete}
```

...and your controller function definition:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
```

Then you don't have to do that $_GET in your controller, Symfony2 does it for you.